# Azure Web App Restart Issue

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have a few applications installed within a single "Web App" on Azure. We've configured each one as an Application (Configure>Virtual Applications and Directories and checkbox checked).

I've noticed that whenever we update a dll in one of the applications all of them get restarted. Any way to prevent this from happening other than creating a separate "Web App" for each application?

We need all of these apps to live under a single domain but remain independent.

I think it is because I have the main site under `"/"` and other applications nested in it. This was done to map the site to the root.

We have it defined this way: Site - `"/"` - mapped to `site\wwwroot` Application - `/account` mapped to `site\account` Pretty much the way it is set in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/09/22/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website.aspx). The physical folders are adjacent and the virtual folders are nested so one would expect that they would not affect each other.

Comment: Please edit your question with details; don't bury details in comments. I just edited your question and moved your comments into the core question, so you can delete your comments.

Comment: I'd guess that when you update a dll (deploy a new version) Azure makes a new instance, then swaps when the new one is ready - so they all appear to get restarted but are actually just started. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable than me can confirm this, or not.

Comment: Yes, this seems to produce downtime which we're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could not find a way to work around this issue. Eventually, we've resorted to azure slot swapping which provides zero downtime: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/